# How to convert this value into absolute value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, absolute-value

I am getting this from webservice 
"rateavg": "2.6111"

now i am getting this in a string. 
How to do this that if it is coming 2.6 it will show 3 and if it will come 2.4 or 2.5 it will show 2 ?

How to get this i am not getting. please help me

Comment: what the answer you expect

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: i am not getting where to start this, i am doing this first time.

Comment: @user6438311 check my answer.

Comment: @user6438311 - below three answer is suitable for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with this, a replica of your query:

```
NSString* str = @"2.611";
double duble = [str floatValue];

NSInteger final = 0;


if (duble > 2.5) {
    final = ceil(duble);
}else{
    final = floor(duble);
}

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)final);
```

So it a case of using either `ceil` or `floor` methods.

Edit: Since you want it for all doubles:

```
NSString* str = @"4.6";
double duble = [str floatValue];

NSInteger final = 0;

NSInteger temp = floor(duble);
double remainder = duble - temp;

if (remainder > 0.5) {
    final = ceil(duble);
}else{
    final = floor(duble);
}

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)final);
```

Comment: it will only for 2.5, if will get another value like 1.6 or 3.7 from the webservice then it will work?

Comment: Does it helped you?

Comment: What about negative values?

Comment: in that case: values of `- 2.611` and `-3.422` will be?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
float f=2.6;
NSLog(@"%.f",f);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about negative values?

Answer (score 1):

plz use this

```
lblHours.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",  [yourstrvalue doubleValue]];
```

update

```
   NSString *a =@"2.67899";
   NSString *b    =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f",  [a doubleValue]];
    // b will contane only one vlue after decimal
    NSArray *array = [b componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    int yourRating;
    if ([[array lastObject] integerValue] > 5) {

        yourRating = [[array firstObject] intValue]+1;

    }
    else
    {
        yourRating = [[array firstObject] intValue];
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",yourRating);
```

Comment: if you want 2.6 then use @"%.01f"

Comment: i dont want 2.6 , i want 3 if i am getting 2.6 and want 2 if i am getting 2.4

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
float floatVal = 2.6111;
long roundedVal = lroundf(floatVal);
NSLog(@"%ld",roundedVal);
```

Comment: check if value is 2.5111 .. :)

Comment: if value is 2.5111 then output is 3

Comment: when give 2.5 it output 3

Comment: if its .5 or above (.6 .7 .8 or .9) you round up to the next whole number, if its .4 or below (.3 .2 .1) you round down to the next whole number

Comment: if you want even 2.5 as 2 then use ceil or floor methods. lroundf gives round off number

Answer (score 1):

Try below code I have tested it and work for every digits,

```
 NSString *str = @"2.7";

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];


NSString *firstDigit = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *secondDigit = [arr objectAtIndex:1];

if (secondDigit.length > 1) {

    secondDigit = [secondDigit substringFromIndex:1];
}

int secondDigitIntValue = [secondDigit intValue];
int firstDigitIntValue = [firstDigit intValue];

if (secondDigitIntValue > 5) {

    firstDigitIntValue = firstDigitIntValue + 1;
}

NSLog(@"final result : %d",firstDigitIntValue);
```

**Or another solution - little bit short**

```
 NSString *str1 = @"2.444";

float my = [str1 floatValue];

NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",my];  // if want result in string

NSLog(@"%@",resultString);

int resultInInt = [resultString intValue]; //if want result in integer
```

Comment: if value is 2.15 @ketan parmar

Comment: then it will return `2` if value is `2.15`!!

Comment: Okay @Ketan parmar

Answer (score 0):

To round value to the nearest integer use `roundf()` function of `math`.

import `math.h` first:

```
#import "math.h"
```

Example,

```
float ValueToRoundPositive;

ValueToRoundPositive = 8.4;

int RoundedValue = (int)roundf(ValueToRoundPositive); //Output: 8

NSLog(@"roundf(%f) = %d", ValueToRoundPositive, RoundedValue);


float ValueToRoundNegative;

ValueToRoundNegative = -6.49;

int RoundedValueNegative = (int)roundf(ValueToRoundNegative); //Output: -6

NSLog(@"roundf(%f) = %d", ValueToRoundNegative, RoundedValueNegative);
```

Read doc here for more information:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/roundf.3.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *value = @"1.23456";
    float floatvalue = value.floatValue;
    int rounded = roundf(floatvalue);
    NSLog(@"%d",rounded);
```

if you what the round with greater value please use `ceil(floatvalue)`

if you what the round with lesser value please use `floor(floatvalue)`

Answer (score 0):

You can round off decimal values by using NSNumberFormatter 
There are some examples you can go through:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setPositiveFormat:@"0.##"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.342]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.3]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0]]);
```

Corresponding results:

```
2010-08-22 15:04:10.614 a.out[6954:903] 25.34
2010-08-22 15:04:10.616 a.out[6954:903] 25.3
2010-08-22 15:04:10.617 a.out[6954:903] 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* str = @"2.61111111";
double value = [str doubleValue];

2.5 -> 3: int num = value+0.5;
2.6 -> 3: int num = value+0.4;
```

Set as your need:

```
double factor = 0.4
if (value < 0) value *= -1;
int num = value+factor;

NSLog(@"%d",num);
```